# Processing different annotations with the same Processor instance

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

We have two annotations in our project and I'd like to collect the annotated classes and create a merged output based on both lists of classes.

Is this possible with only one `Processor` instance? How do I know if the `Processor` instance was called with every annotated class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The framework calls the `Processor.process` method only once (per round) and you can access both lists at the same time through the passed `RoundEnvironment` parameter. So you can process both lists in the same `process` method call.

To do this list both annotations in the `SupportedAnnotationTypes` annotation:

```
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({ 
    "hu.palacsint.annotation.MyAnnotation", 
    "hu.palacsint.annotation.MyOtherAnnotation" 
})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
public class Processor extends AbstractProcessor { ... }
```

Here is a sample `process` method:

```
@Override
public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
        final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    System.out.println("   > ---- process method starts " + hashCode());
    System.out.println("   > annotations: " + annotations);

    for (final TypeElement annotation: annotations) {
        System.out.println("   >  annotation: " + annotation.toString());
        final Set<? extends Element> annotateds = 
            roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
        for (final Element element: annotateds) {
            System.out.println("      > class: " + element);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("   > processingOver: " + roundEnv.processingOver());
    System.out.println("   > ---- process method ends " + hashCode());
    return false;
}
```

And its output:

```
   > ---- process method starts 21314930
   > annotations: [hu.palacsint.annotation.MyOtherAnnotation, hu.palacsint.annotation.MyAnnotation]
   >  annotation: hu.palacsint.annotation.MyOtherAnnotation
      > class: hu.palacsint.annotation.p2.OtherClassOne
   >  annotation: hu.palacsint.annotation.MyAnnotation
      > class: hu.palacsint.annotation.p2.ClassTwo
      > class: hu.palacsint.annotation.p3.ClassThree
      > class: hu.palacsint.annotation.p1.ClassOne
   > processingOver: false
   > ---- process method ends 21314930
   > ---- process method starts 21314930
   > roots: []
   > annotations: []
   > processingOver: true
   > ---- process method ends 21314930
```

It prints all classes which are annotated with the `MyAnnotation` or the `MyOtherAnnotation` annotation.