# How to access @XmlElement values in APT?

Tags: java, annotations, java-6, apt, annotation-processing

I'm processing annotations with APT in compile time, and I need to get the values of `@XmlElement` annotations in some classes. The class looks something like this:

```
public class ComponentConfig {

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(type = Sample1.class, name = "sample-1-config"),
        @XmlElement(type = Sample2.class, name = "sample-2-config"),
        @XmlElement(type = Sample3.class, name = "sample-3-config"),
    })

    //...
}
```

I'd like to get the `name` value of the `@XmlElement`, but the following processor code cannot fetch it for me:

```
List<? extends AnnotationMirror> annotationMirrors = element.getAnnotationMirrors();
for (AnnotationMirror mirror : annotationMirrors) {
    if (mirror.getAnnotationType().toString().equals(XML_ELEMENT)) {
        System.out.println(getAnnotationValueMapValueOfName(mirror));
        nodes.add(getAnnotationValueMapValueOfName(mirror));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not APT, but it works with the [`AbstractProcessor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html) of JDK6+:

```
@Override
public boolean process(final Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, 
        final RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    checkEnvironmentChange();
    System.out.println("   > ---- process2 method starts " + hashCode());
    System.out.println("   > annotations: " + annotations);

    for (final TypeElement annotation: annotations) {
        System.out.println("   >  annotation: " + annotation.toString());
        processAnnotation(roundEnv, annotation);
    }
    System.out.println("   > processingOver: " + roundEnv.processingOver());
    System.out.println("   > ---- process2 method ends " + hashCode());
    return false;
}

private void processAnnotation(final RoundEnvironment roundEnv, 
        final TypeElement annotation) {
    final Set<? extends Element> annotateds = 
            roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
    for (final Element element: annotateds) {
        processElement(element);
    }
}

private void processElement(final Element element) {
    System.out.println("      > class: " + element);
    System.out.println("      > class2: " + element.getClass());
    final List<? extends Element> enclosedElements = 
            element.getEnclosedElements();
    for (final Element enclosedElement: enclosedElements) {
        processEnclosedElement(enclosedElement);
    }
}

private void processEnclosedElement(final Element enclosedElement) {
    final XmlElements xmlElements = 
            enclosedElement.getAnnotation(XmlElements.class);
    if (xmlElements == null) {
        return;
    }
    final XmlElement[] xmlElemntValues = xmlElements.value();
    for (final XmlElement xmlElementValue: xmlElemntValues) {
        System.out.println("           > name: " + xmlElementValue.name());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[...]
   > annotations: [hu.palacsint.annotation.MyAnnotation]
   >  annotation: hu.palacsint.annotation.MyAnnotation
      > class: hu.palacsint.annotation.p2.ClassTwo
      > class2: class com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$ClassSymbol
           > name: sample-1-config
           > name: sample-2-config
           > name: sample-3-config
   > processingOver: false
[...]
```

My former question also could help: [Processing different annotations with the same Processor instance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11713059/843804)

Answer (score 1):

Where is `XML_ELEMENT` defined? It should at least be a fully qualified name.

Using `getAnnotationType().toString()` is not a good basis to do the comparison.

If you printed out the values of all `getAnnotationType().toString()` that you find, you might spot your problem.

Also should be using `javax.annotation.processing` package as APT is now deprecated (as it has recently been removed from the build for the upcoming JDK8 - IIRC). It is a bit nicer to use, and supported by all JDK6+ implementations.

Comment: +1, Good to know that APT is deprecated. I've just found a blog entry about it: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/apt_ending